# (help)Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android-studio, textview

so im making an app in android studio and i  trying to invoke setText() on a TextView thats in a fragment' and im trying to invoke it from my mainActivity.

but i says its a null refrence, the weird thing is im using this exact same code in another function and it workes there so i dont know why it doesnt here.

The function that doesnt work:

```
 public void readUsersFromData() {
        DatabaseReference Users_ref_Data = db.getReference("Users");
        String searchName = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.socialSearchBar)).getText().toString().trim();
        Users_ref_Data.child(searchName).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {

                DataSnapshot dataSnapshot = task.getResult();
                User user = new User(dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class));

                if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                    if (task.getResult().exists()) {
                        TextView name = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.profileName));
                        TextView email = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.profileEmail));
                        TextView number = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.profilePhoneNum));
                        name.setText("Name: " + user.getName());
                        email.setText("Mail: " + user.getMail());
                        number.setText("Phone number: " + user.getNumber());



                    } else {

//                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "User Doesn't Exist", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }


                } else {

//                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Failed to read", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }
        });


    }
```

and the one that does:

```
public void getMyUserData() {
        DatabaseReference Users_ref_Data = db.getReference("Users");
        Users_ref_Data.child(mainUserName.toString()).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {

                DataSnapshot dataSnapshot = task.getResult();
                User user = new User(dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class));

                if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                    if (task.getResult().exists()) {
//                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Successfully Read", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        TextView name = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.profileName));
                        TextView email = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.profileEmail));
                        TextView number = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.profilePhoneNum));
                        name.setText("Name: " + user.getName());
                        email.setText("Mail: " + user.getMail());
                        number.setText("Phone number: " + user.getNumber());


                    } else {

//                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "User Doesn't Exist", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }


                } else {

//                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Failed to read", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }
        });

    }
```

if you guys need more code just tell me im activly looking at this qustion.

Comment: One of your `findViewById` methods must be returning `null`. Have you double-checked the names of your resources?

Comment: yes its the correct ID, againe this code is copy paseted from the working function, but in the other function it returns null...